# How to heap buffer flow to find first and last positon of element in sorted array

Tags: c, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Here is my code
I have used P as the array containing elements, l - low, h - high, returning last and first address through r, used binary search to find the element(target element is T). Getting heap memory overflow, can someone explain the error in this code.

```
int g=0;
void binsearch(int * p, int l, int h, int t, int *r)
{
    if(h>=l)
    {
        int mid = l+ (h-l)/2;
        if(*(p+mid)==t)
        {
            g++;
            r=(int*)realloc(r,g*sizeof(int));
            *(r+g-1) = *(p+mid);
        }
        binsearch(p,l,mid-1,t,r);
        binsearch(p,mid+1,h,t,r);

    }

}

int* searchRange(int* p, int n, int t, int* r)
{   

    r=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    *(r+0)=-1;
    *(r+1)=-1;

    binsearch(p,0,n,t,r);
    if(*(r)== -1)
    {
        return r;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strlen(r)==1)
        {
            r=(int*)realloc(r,sizeof(int)*2);
            *(r+1)=*(r+0);
        }
        else
        {
            *(r+1)=*(r+strlen(r)-1);    
        }

        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: And in the beginning of `searchRange` you malloc to `r` which is an argument that has been malloced memory in the previous call of the recursion: you throw that memory away.

Comment: In `binSearch`: `r=(int*)realloc(r,g*sizeof(int));` but `realloc` can return a different address. The caller won't see that.

Comment: In `searchRange`: `r=(int*)realloc(r,sizeof(int)*2);`: Tihs will always "realloc" the same size. Also, since `r` is of type `int *`, then `strlen(r)` is invalid: it is not a string. If you need to know the size of `r` you must pass it as a separate argument.